# Web Component "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-component, custom-element

I have created a very basic custom element, that can change its value based on a provided attribute `person`. But whenever I'm loading my custom element I get this error: `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`.  When I add a breakpoint to the attributeChangedCallback function I can indeed see that on load the element is not there. When I continue loading though the element loads perfectly.

I could imagine because I'm using webpack to bundle all my files that the issue comes from loading the element at the end of the body instead of loading the element inside my head.

**my-element.js:**

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
     super();

     this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
     this._person = '';
  }

  get person() {
     return this._name;
  }

  set person(val) {
     this.setAttribute('person', val);
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
     return ['person'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
     let myElementInner = this.shadow.querySelector('.my-element-inner');

     switch (attrName) {
        case 'person':
           this._person = newVal;

           // ======================
           // The error occures here
           // ======================
           myElementInner.innerHTML = `My name is ${this._person}`;

     }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
     var template =
     `
        <style>
        .my-element-inner {
           outline: blue dashed 1px;
           background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
        }
        </style>
        <span class="my-element-inner">My name is ${this._person}</span>
     `

     this.shadow.innerHTML = template;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WebPack Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <my-element person="André"></my-element>

  <!-- Here goes the bundle.js -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `this.shadow` get the value from ` this.createShadowRoot();` which you are using as `this.shadow.querySelector('.my-element-inner');` so what will be the value returned from `this.createShadowRoot();`? Debug that and you will get your solution.

Comment: What happens when you log `myElementInner` right after it is declared? Is there even a value there?

Comment: Is this your entire class definition? Where is the definition for createShadowRoot()?

Comment: @JoelKoh it is undefined, that is what I don't quite understand

Comment: @JonWarren sorry for that it is acctually `this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attributeChangedCallback()` can be called before or after the `connectedCallback` depending on how your custom element is used.

If you move the `connectedCallback` logic to the constructor then things will be fine

Another option would be to check if `myElementInner` is `null` and keep your code in the `connectedCallback`

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this._person = '';
    var template =
      `
        <style>
        .my-element-inner {
           outline: blue dashed 1px;
           background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
        }
        </style>
        <span class="my-element-inner">My name is ${this._person}</span>
     `

    this.shadow.innerHTML = template;
  }

  get person() {
    return this._person;
  }

  set person(val) {
    this.setAttribute('person', val);
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['person'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    let myElementInner = this.shadow.querySelector('.my-element-inner');

    switch (attrName) {
      case 'person':
        this._person = newVal;
        if (myElementInner) {
          myElementInner.innerHTML = `My name is ${this._person}`;
        }

    }
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WebPack Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <my-element person="André"></my-element>

  <!-- Here goes the bundle.js -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AndréKuhlmann cool , the following is [recommended reading](https://gist.github.com/praveenpuglia/0832da687ed5a5d7a0907046c9ef1813) in case you need to know more

Answer (score 0):

Since the spec [encourages](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance) pushing as much setup as possible to the `connectedCallback`, this might be preferable for some developers.

Note that `attributeChangedCallback` can still be called while the raw HTML is being parsed if any (observed) attributes are present on the element. For cases like these, I use a private `#mounted` property. This property is useful for preventing chunks of logic in `connectedCallback` from running redundantly (see the link to the spec above), but it can also be useful for preventing `attributeChangedCallback` from running prematurely.

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  #mounted = false;
  #person = '';

  constructor() {
     super();
     this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }

  get person() {
     return this.#person;
  }

  set person(val) {
     this.setAttribute('person', val);
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
     return ['person'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
     if (!this.#mounted) return;
     let myElementInner = this.shadow.querySelector('.my-element-inner');

     switch (attrName) {
        case 'person':
           this.#person = newVal;
           myElementInner.innerHTML = `My name is ${this.#person}`;
     }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
     const template = `
        <style>
        .my-element-inner {
           outline: blue dashed 1px;
           background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
        }
        </style>
        <span class="my-element-inner">My name is ${this.#person}</span>
     `

     this.shadow.innerHTML = template;
     this.#mounted = true;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```